# SQL in BigQuery - How to loop through every month in a timeframe and calculate some metrics (i.e. count userID)

Tags: sql, loops, google-bigquery

I am doing a test to calculate user retention for a bank. While doing so, I can certainly calculate the number of churn users and number of loyal users for a certain date period (for example, from 1 jan to 1 feb). However, the timeframe has every transactions/activities of every unique user from 1 jan 2016 to 1 jun 2018. I know we could do a loop in sql to automatically loop through every month but it is hard to do so with the calculation (with new users joining every month and the new users of month 1 would either be loyal user or churn in month 2).
Could anybody shed a light for me?

Comment: I'd suggest making up some sample data that would illustrate your puzzle and post that sample data along with your desired outcome corresponding to that sample.  That way if there are those of us out here who might want to try and solve, we would have some data to work with.  Obviously make up some trivial data that illustrates the puzzle and do NOT post real data.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on that?